# Facebook permissions for sharing content

Tags: facebook, permissions

I am building an app that displays 'shared' content from 2 friends on Facebook.

e.g. Photos that both users are tagged in.

I would like either user to then be able to share the resulting content with their friends.

This does mean than if you weren't friends with one of the users, you potentially could still see content 'owned' by them, regardless of whatever privacy settings they have put against that content (as your friend has shared the joint content).

Is there a permission that extends content privacy?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of extending or changing the user's privacy settings on their account. While you can change the permission of content they share via your app, you cannot update the settings for content that has already been shared via your app - only the user can control that.

In addition, the user's lowest privacy setting will always be the maximum privacy setting you can use. E.g., if the user has set wall post to be "Friends", you app cannot then post things as "public". You will be able to use "Friends" or lower in your app.